# Python requests: Url will show table in browser but not when I use requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a table in a webpage, or even download the .xlsx file of this table, using the requests library.

Normal workflow:

I log into the site. Go to my reporting page, choose report, click button that says "Test" and a second window opens up with my table and gives me the option to download the .xlsx file.

When I try to access this url I can copy and paste it into any chrome browser that I am currently logged into. When I try with requests, even when passing an auth into my get() i get a 200 response but it is a simple page with one line of text telling me to "contact my tech staff to receive the proper url to enter your username and password". This is the same as when i paste the url into a browser where I am not logged into the site. Except when I do that i am redirected to a new url that has the same sentence.

So I imagine there is a slug for the organization that is not passed in the url but somewhere in the headers or cookies when I access this site in my browser. How do i identify this parameter in the HTTP header? Then how do I send it to requests so I can get my table and move on to try and automate downloading the .xlsx.

```
import requests

url = 'myorganization.com/adhocHTML.xsl?x=adhoc.AdHocFilter-listAdhocData&filterID=45678&source=live'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=('username', 'Password'))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to the requests library and just trying to automate some data flow before it ever gets to analyzing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to login with requests. You can do this with making a session and make other requests with this session (it will save all cookies and other stuffs).

---

Before going for code you should do a few steps:
make sure you are logged out. open browser Inspect in log in page. go to network tab. log in and find a POST request in network tab that is related to your login request. at the end of this tab you find some parameters for login. make does parameters a dictionary (login_data) in your code and go as below:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.post('url_to_login_page', login_data)
data = session.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Login data for each website are different from others so I can't give you a specific example. You should be able to find it as I said above. If you had problem with those, tell me.

Comment: first I think you have used your own data in this comment. I suggest deleting them.

Comment: make sure that you have entered correct login URL. you can find it inside the same POST request that you have found your login_info at the top of the page. It can be different from the URL page that you login from your browser (in browser it might be redirecting you to another URL)

Comment: Thanks for the help you were right about the url. I now have gotten to the proper looking page but the table has 0 results. Do i need to go through all of the clicks that get me to the reporting page and pass those things through to the headers dict. Is there a method for looking for what is missing that is more logical than that?

Comment: I don't really know what you want but you should get the information from another URL find it in your browser the change it in the code where you make get request. Then for finding specific information you can use BeautifulSoup (for more static pages) or Selenium (for more dynamic pages).